# How to properly use -MD flag in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile where make only recompiles necessary `.cpp` files.

By default, it works well if I edit `.cpp`, however, when I edit `.h` files, it just ignores the changes.

So I've read of `-MD` flag and its friend `-MP` (used to avoid bugs when typing make).

However, I can't seem to make it working, if I use `-MMD`, it works perfectly but I rely on system includes too as I'm writing a library too that is evolving along with the project. Thus, if I update the libary header and reinstall the library, typing `make` in the main project should recompiles files that includes the changed header.

When using `-MMD` flag, it - as expected - does not recompile the project, however, using `-MD` flag, it does recompile everything. In fact, `-MD` recompiles everything every time, even when nothing changed.

Here is a minimal project structure that reproduce the issue:

#### ./Makefile:

```
all: build

re: clean build

build: build_lib install_lib build_client

build_lib:
    $(MAKE) -C lib
    $(MAKE) install -C lib

build_client:
    $(MAKE) -C client

install_lib:
    $(MAKE) install -C lib


.PHONY: clean
clean: clean_lib clean_client

clean_lib:
    $(MAKE) clean -C lib

clean_client:
    $(MAKE) clean -C client
```

#### ./client/Makefile:

```
CC = g++
INC = -I../lib
CXXFLAGS = -Wall $(INC) -g -MD -MP
EXEC_NAME = ../test

src = $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.cpp')
obj = $(src:.cpp=.o)

LIBRARIES = -ltest_lib
LDFLAGS = -rdynamic $(LIBRARIES)

all: $(EXEC_NAME)

re: clean $(EXEC_NAME)

$(EXEC_NAME): $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
-include $(obj:.o=.d)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(obj) $(EXEC_NAME)
```

#### ./lib/Makefile:

```
.PHONY : clean

CXXFLAGS= -fPIC -g -Itest_lib/include -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS= -shared

SOURCES = $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.cpp')
HEADERS = $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.h')
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

TARGET=libtest_lib.so
INC_FOLDER=test_lib/include
CUR_DIR = $(shell pwd)

all: $(TARGET)

install:
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libtest_lib.so && sudo ln -s $(CUR_DIR)/$(TARGET) /usr/local/lib/libtest_lib.so
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/test_lib && sudo cp -r $(INC_FOLDER) /usr/local/include/test_lib

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

#### ./client/main.cpp:

```
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    Bar b;

    b.sayHello();
    b.sayBye();

    return 0;
}
```

#### ./client/bar.h

```
#ifndef __BAR__
#define __BAR__

#include <test_lib/foo.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    Bar() {};
    ~Bar() {};

    void sayBye() const {
        std::cout << "Bye " << name << "..." << std::endl;
    };
};

#endif
```

#### ./lib/test_lib/include/foo.h

```
#ifndef __FOO__
#define __FOO__

struct Foo
{
    const char *name;

    Foo(const char *name = "world");
    ~Foo();

    void sayHello() const;
};

#endif
```

#### ./lib/test_lib/src

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo(const char *name) : name(name) {}
Foo::~Foo() {}

void Foo::sayHello() const
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << " !" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that still shows the issue, you need to show an example of your include directives and folder structure.

Comment: We can't help given this info.  I think you can debug this yourself.  First, find the `.d` files that are generated and look at them.  Are they in the right place?  That is for every `srcdir/foo.c` is there a `srcdir/foo.d` file?  Do the contents seem sane?  Are the target names correct for the `.o` files?  Are the prerequisite paths correct?  If that seems fine, then run `make -d` (redirect the voluminous output to a file).  Locate the process make goes through to decide to rebuild a sample `.o`.  It will tell you exactly what files were out of date.  Is it right?

Comment: @MadScientist `make -d` indeed helped here. and I understand what's going on here, see my edit, I'm actually reinstalling the library everytime so it thinks the file has changed based on its date. I think I can figure out a better way to update the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I copied the library headers all the time in `/usr/local` so the files got newer and the client make then thought every header of the library had changed.

A simple fix to this problem was to replace in the library Makefile the following line:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/test_lib && sudo cp -r $(INC_FOLDER) /usr/local/include/test_lib`

by

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/test_lib && sudo ln -s $(CUR_DIR)/$(INC_FOLDER) /usr/local/include/test_lib`

On a side note, provided example is missing the removal of `.d` files on the clean rule.